# Recyclе viеw backgrоund colоr nоt wоrk

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i stuck with next thing.

When i set background color (for example orange) on my device i get another (purple). Pictures below. Command setBackground it's last command and if i delete it color stay primary (in my case it's white).

I need change color dynamically from adapter class so set background from xml can't help.

I checked styles, colors and xml files but it's given nothing. Maybe some one stuck with it or have any ideas how solve it?

Thank to all.

[image: First image with part of code]

[image: Second image with result on device]

[image: Picture of adapter]

[image: Pictures of item of adapter]

[image: Parent layout that placed in ViewHolder class]

Comment: hey can you add the xml of your adapter layout

Comment: yeah, now i uploading it

Comment: `holder.parentLayout`, what `parentLayout` refers to, paste xml of that particularly

Comment: parentLayout initialized in ViewHolder Class. I added ViewHolder with parentLayout and xml where parentLayout placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass in a resolved color (Android Studio should [warn about this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A8h6.png)). Values in `R.` are int values, and when you pass them directly to `setBackgroundColor()` that int value is parsed as a color, but is not indicative of the actual color as this is just a resource ID. Do as the warning in my screenshot says

```
Resources res = holder.parentLayout.getResources();
holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.paymentBackground));
```

Or

```
Context context = holder.parentLayout.getContext();
holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.paymentBackground));
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, i didn't know it. When i changed color with ContextCompat it's started work. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Do it via xml

```
        android:background="@color/paymentBackground"
```

Comment: Hi, thank but it's not solution, I need change color dynamically from adapter class